# JDBC persistence allows only shared store HA options

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want use PostgreSQL for persistence of ActiveMQ Artemis, but it's not working and shows the error "JDBC persistence allows only Shared Store HA options":

```
ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224097: Failed to start server
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JDBC persistence allows only Shared Store HA options
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createNodeManager(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:588) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:687) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:605) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:66) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:129) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:212) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:162) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:144) ~[artemis-boot.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:61) ~[artemis-boot.jar:2.28.0]
```

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<store>
   <database-store>
      <data-source-properties>
         <data-source-property key="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
         <data-source-property key="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/artemis" />
         <data-source-property key="username" value="user" />
         <data-source-property key="password" value="password" />
         <data-source-property key="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
      </data-source-properties>
      <bindings-table-name>BINDINGS</bindings-table-name>
      <message-table-name>MESSAGES</message-table-name>
      <large-message-table-name>LARGE_MESSAGES</large-message-table-name>
      <page-store-table-name>PAGE_STORE</page-store-table-name>
      <node-manager-store-table-name>NODE_MANAGER_STORE</node-manager-store-table-name>
   </database-store>
</store>
```

Comment: Can you add your ha-policy settings to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `shared-store` `ha-policy`, e.g. on the primary broker:

```xml
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
      <master/>
   </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

And on the backup:

```xml
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
      <slave/>
   </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```